# Windows phone emulator error at Windows Server 2012 r2

Tags: windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2015, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-phone-8-emulator

I have installed Visual Studio 2015 Community with Windows Phone 8.1 SDK(installed with custom installation at Visual Studio). When I created empty Windows phone 8.1 application and deploy it, I got an errors - DP6100 and DP6200. Emulator didn't load Windows phone OS and run empty program. Repair Windows phone SDK didn't help. Can anybody help me? I'm new at Windows Server 2012 r2, and I start using it only because my notebook doesn't support Hyper-V(processor) and I want to start develop Windows phone applications.

Comment: is the windows server 2-12 r2 a virtual machine or real computer?  I dont think the emulators will run an hyper-v VM

Comment: Windows Server 2012 r2 - real computer. My wife notebook. I connect to it via Microsoft Remote Desktop.

Comment: looks like the phone emulators only run on windows 8 pro, 8.1 pro, and 10 pro

Comment: Thanks for help! It's a pity! Maybe there are still ways to run Windows phone development, when wife using her notebook?